# bash script assign variable to an associative array

Tags: arrays, bash, associative

I have been struggling with a new concept to me - associative arrays in a bash script.

Here is simplified version of my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A MYID
MYID[hello]=world
tac /home/user/filename | while read -r line; do
  MYID[hello]=me
done
echo "${MYID[hello]}"
exit
```

This is what I thought it would do:
1) declare an associative array called MYID
2) in MYID assign the value world to the key hello
3) read the file /home/user/filename backwards line by line
4) every time it reads a line assign me to the key hello in the MYID array
5) print out "me" and exit

What it does do is print out "world" instead of "me".  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pipe creates a subshell, so any changes you make to `MYID` in the while loop only exist in that subshell. Try this instead:

```
while read -r line; do
    MYID[hello]=me
done < <(tac /home/user/filename)
```

Comment: Thank-you, this seems to work.  I will add this to my list of things to learn.